# setOnClickListener for Android Image Slider in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, onclick, android-viewpager

I have implemented [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) to a GridView and when click on gridView i want to perform a task. but the problem is since ImageSlider taking whole area in GridView if i click on it, GridView click event not triggering.

i thought since imageSlider using touchEvent to slide images it might have disabled click event. but i couldnt find it in the library.

i have checkbox in my gridview i want to make it checked or unchecked when ever user clicked on GridView.

```
        mViewHolder.imageViewSlider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("CLICKED","CLICKED"); // this is not triggering
            }
        });

      convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
             // This is Working
              mViewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(!mViewHolder.checkBox.isChecked());
                }
       });
```

#### Update

but there is eachslider on click method. but i dont know how to trigger the checkbox using that.

```
for(){
    DefaultSliderView textSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(mContext);
    textSliderView        
        .image(imagePath)
        .setOnSliderClickListener(this)
        .description(""+position)
        .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.FitCenterCrop);

    mViewHolder.imageView.addSlider(textSliderView);
}


   @Override
    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
      // This one gets triggered but no idea making checkbox trigger
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using following method to update Database and Reload the ListView. in that way i was able to tick the checkbox.

```
public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
      // This one gets triggered but no idea making checkbox trigger
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make your own adapter to extend the gridView elements. In your case that adapter would be of AndroidImageSlider elements.

Example of what I have done in my case:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private int iw, ih;
    private String tag = "**Template wallpapers**";

    private Activity myActivity;

    private ImageLoader imageLoader = null;

    public ImageAdapter(Activity activity, Context c) {
        myActivity = activity;
        mContext = c;
        iw = commonClass.iwidth;
        ih = commonClass.iheight;

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MainActivity_GridView.mThumbIds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return MainActivity_GridView.mThumbIds.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = myActivity.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.image.getLayoutParams().width = iw;
            holder.image.getLayoutParams().height = ih;
            holder.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.image.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        if(MainActivity_GridView.mThumbIds.get(position).matches("\\d+")){
            String imageUri = "drawable://" + MainActivity_GridView.mThumbIds.get(position);
            ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(holder.image, false);
            imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageAware);
        }else{
            String imageUri = MainActivity_GridView.mThumbIds.get(position);
            ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(holder.image, false);
            imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageAware);
        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

Then, just listen to gridView clicks:

```
GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
ImageAdapter imAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, context);

imAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
gv.invalidateViews();
gv.setAdapter(imAdapter);

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // item has been clicked
            // you got the ID - so use that info to do what you want ^
        }
    });
```

Comment: GridView ItemClickListner is working. but the problem is when click in on ImageSlider does not trigger the GridView click listener

Comment: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) - here make a view listener for your AndroidImageSlider.